# How to write Simplex method (in tableau/matrix form) from scratch in python?

Tags: python, operations-research, simplex-algorithm

I have got my equations and everything set. I just don't know how to iterate, i.e. how to update A, b and c. I have been trying with the matrix form. If anybody could help with that or the tableau form, it would be amazing!
My problem is simple:
min cx s,t Ax=b where this includes in itself slack variables, and thus an obvious choice for initial bfs.

Answer (score -1):

You could try setting the variables as in input

```
A = input("what is A equal to")
```

and than after that run the rest of your program